# Did I hit a bug in the Triage review?

Tags: support, review-queues, triage

Here's what happened.

I'm reviewing post in the Triage review queue, the first post I marked as "Should be improved".

The next one has a warning of "Stop! Look and Listen" bla bla, 
then I accidentally pressed <kbd>CMD + R</kbd> (refresh), and after reload I have this:

[image]

Then stack overflow is warning me:

[image]

It's kind of depressing being warned like that. I even edit post that I'm marking as "Should be improved" if possible.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Did you read what happened sir? i did not marked it as "should be improved". i accidentally pressed "cmd + r"

Comment: No, you failed the **first** review. You had already failed it when you hit CMD-R. There was no second review here.

Comment: You even said, *"the first post i marked it as "Should be improved""*. That was the one you failed. The next screen wasn't another review. It was telling you that you failed the previous audit

Comment: But why is that link, linking to that post with -10 down votes?

Comment: Because it was an audit taken from a question that was posted that other users correctly saw as spam and downvoted

Comment: Because that is the post you were reviewing. You shouldn't have clicked "Should be improved". Since it's spam (as indicated by Martjin) it is no good

Comment: @0yeoj: you were being audited; tested to see if you were paying attention. A known-bad post was shown to you with the voting reset to see if you would recognise it as a bad post. You did not and failed the audit. Because this wasn't your first failed audit (you failed one yesterday as well, for example) you have been temporarily banned from reviewing to make sure you learn and to protect the reviewing system from people that don't pay attention or don't quite know how to review.

Comment: Thank you everyone, @MartijnPieters, can you add that long comment to your answer? I'll be accepting that as the answer. Now i understand. But still i'm sure i'm 100% paying attention. hmm.. I probably need to double it or maybe more keen in reviewing.

Comment: @0yeoj Think of it like this: you've *not* been banned. You've been sent on vacation to think about why you hit "should be improved" on a question which should have made you foam at the mouth and wish that you had the tools to erase it from the internet right then and there ;) Perhaps you're too hesitant to full-out reject questions and answers?

Comment: @0yeoj one thing that might help is to think of what action would be taken since you clicked "Should be improved". Is there any action you could take to improve that post without completely rewriting it? Hopefully your answer is "no" since it is spam and not asking a question. Then you will realize that it is unsalvageable.

Comment: @Gimby, Yes.. That's is exactly what i have in mind. the "not so bad" post.. Since this is world wide, I dont know what's inside the head of the person posting it. I mostly mark posts as "should be improved" giving chance for the author to edit their post.. But.. My.. I'm kind of depressed for thinking so much, trying to understand peoples difficulty in expressing what they have in mind.. anyway i'll be more keen next time, and a bit strict. :)

Comment: @codeMagic.. my comment above goes for you too bud. :)

Comment: @0yeoj " I mostly mark posts as "should be improved" giving chance for the author to edit their post." That's basically another form of robo-reviewing, only just not with the intent of earning badges. The audit system has done its job well in this case. You should stop doing that as it is destructive to the reviewing process. This is not about being nice - this is about sifting out the shit so the good questions (and answers) get all the chance to be seen and responded to.

Comment: @Gimby, Yes sir! I'll surely do that after two days.. hahaha. But i'm not robo reviewing actually im doing extra work.. I go to the actual post then i edit it myself if i think it's editable and i have knowledge and understanding on what the post/question is all about..  And I dont want to see that warning again. haha..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You failed an audit on the first post, which is why you got a *Stop! Look and Listen* message. There was no second review.

You were correctly banned from reviewing. You approved a *spam* post, you should have selected *Unsalvageable* instead.

In case you did not understand this: you were being audited; tested to see if you were paying attention. A known-bad post was shown to you with the voting reset to see if you would recognise it as a bad post. Once you complete the audit the original post is shown to you together with the outcome of the audit; if you failed the audit you are told to *Stop! Look and Listen*.

You had failed the audit. Because this wasn't your first failed audit (you failed one yesterday as well, for example) you have been temporarily banned from reviewing to make sure you learn and to protect the reviewing system from people that don't pay attention or don't quite know how to review.

I do hope you learn from this and in future review more carefully.